# how to get the sum of values in 2 textboxes that gets updated C#

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, sum, textbox

I have 2 textboxes that get updated regularly, via serial port each of them displays data on 1 line, I want to get the sum of these values from these textboxes and put the sum into another text box.

Code:

```
value 1 and 2 are type string
textbox1.text = value1;
textbox2.text = value2;

double value3 = convert.ToDouble(value1) + convert.ToDouble(value2);
textbox3.text = value3.ToString();
```

Output textbox1:

```
100, after sometime updates to 200, then 300
```

Output textbox2:

```
50, after sometime updates to 100, then 150
```

What I'm getting, output in textbox3:

```
150, after some time updates to 300, then 450
```

The value I should get is

```
100+200+300+50+100+150
```

Comment: Who is updating them regulary? Is it the user? If it is some automatic process, this should be entirely handeled in code behind. It is a common mistake to have data only exist in the UI.

Comment: automatic via serial port

Comment: Storing data in the GUI is a classical mistake. The GUI should only ever be a representation of the data in the code behind. You should do all work with the data in the code behind. Avoid reading stuff from the GUI was far as possible.

Comment: im assuming a better way would be to put the data into the list and getting the sum of the list? is  there an easier way?

Comment: What way *could* be faster then already having the data at hand? I also do not see any reason for a Collection. It is 2 input values and 1 output value.

Comment: i guess you're right i thought this would be much easier than expected, turns out not

Comment: Surprisingly many things in programming are "more trouble then they have any right to be". Trying to access the GUI for anything *but* userinput is a common beginners mistake. And with WPF/UWP and a proper MVVM pattern we do not even need to do that much anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved my own problem, ill post here in case someone else might be in the same position

```
used two lists got the sums and added the sums
```

```
List<double> totalvalueList = new List<double>();
totalvalueList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(value1));
            double totalval = totalvalueList.Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will work for you

**1) Declare below at class level:**

```
List<double> txbxList1 = new List<double>();
List<double> txbxList2 = new List<double>();
```

**2) Use below code with the TextChanged event for both textbox1 and textbox2**

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txbxList1.Add(double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
        textBox3.Text = sumList().ToString();
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txbxList2.Add(double.Parse(textBox2.Text));
        textBox3.Text = sumList().ToString();
    }

    private double sumList()
    {
        double sum = 0;

        foreach(double d in txbxList1)
        {
            sum += d;
        }

        foreach (double d in txbxList2)
        {
            sum += d;
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

When you are getting input from text field in C# you will get string data as input. For integer operations, you need to convert your string input from text using `Parse` method.

Try

```
Int16.Parse()
Int32.Parse()
Int64.Parse()
```

Comment: Sorry for a downvote but this does not attempt to answer the question. And you don't explain how it is the answer in your view.